# Gradle module dependent on Spring Boot module refuses to start up Web Environment

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have a Spring Boot Web application as a Gradle module `foo`. (in fact, they are split into multiple modules, but for simplicity lets consider them as a single module).

Now, I'd like to add Karate Integration tests as a **separate Gradle module** that is dependent on the Spring Boot application. Let's call it `bar`. It should run as a JUnit tests and start up the Spring Boot web environment on a random port.

I achieved this as such:

`foo` Spring Boot web app `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

`foo` Spring Boot entry point:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

`bar` Integration Tests module `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':foo')

    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}
```

`bar` Integration Test sample

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyApplication.class, webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class BarTest {

    @LocalServerPort
    int serverPort;

    @Test
    void test() {
        // Simple example. This will run all the complex integration tests
        assertEquals(8080, serverPort);
    }
}
```

Note how the integration test in `bar` references the main application entry point `MyApplication` in `foo` in the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

Now comes the weird part: **This works fine when I run the test from my IntelliJ IDE, but does not work when run from Gradle**

If I run the test from my IDE, the first lines show this:

```
10:12:03.327 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [BarTest], using SpringBootContextLoader
```

It then goes on to spin up the Web Context until it is fully loaded and the test passes.

But if I run it from Gradle with --info, I see the following instead:

```
10:14:06.226 [Test worker] INFO org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContextBootstrapper - Neither @ContextConfiguration nor @ContextHierarchy found for test class [BarTest], using DelegatingSmartContextLoader
```

It does not spin up a web context, and the test fails by being unable to inject `@LocalServerPort`

It looks like it uses the wrong TestContextBootstrapper. How to fix this?

Comment: The Spring Boot module isn't a regular jar, but a fat jar with a different structure. As such it cannot be used as a dependency in other modules, as classes won't be available. It works in your ride because it probably adds the project instead of the jar as a dependency.

Comment: Any idea how to achieve what I am trying to achieve? Having a separate Gradle module spin up a Spring Boot Web Environment to run integration tests against?

Comment: launch the application before you run the tests. Do this with a gradle task and on a well known port. Or move the integration tests to the same module.